# What is the correct expression of "melancholic/blue man"?

Tags: expressions

Just to mean someone is in melancholic/blue state. Not sure about how to express it properly in English

Comment: He's sad. He's gloomy. He's glum. He's got the blues. He's depressed. He's an Eyeore. He's a doom-and-gloomer. There are dozens of ways to "express it properly in English." However, if you are [only looking for a noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168984/what-is-the-correct-expression-of-melancholic-blue-man/168986#comment351404_168986), instead of short phrase or sentence, then you should probably edit your question, and make that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that that person

> [**feels blue**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feel+blue)
>
> [**feels down (in the dumps (or *mouth*))**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Down+in+the+Dumps)
>
> [**feels downhearted**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/downhearted)
>
> [**feels in low spirits**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/low+spirits)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context:

*transient*

"John is **sad** today." or colloquially "John is **blue** today"

*persistent*

"John is **depressed."**

*persistent, deep, and lacking a cause by circumstances*

"John is clinically depressed."

Comment: Then how to express it as a noun? A men feeling blue?

Comment: @cqcn1991  Do you mean the English equivalent to "Les Misérables"

Comment: Ah...No. I just want to know how to say someone is `blue`.

Comment: @cqcn1991  Saying *John is blue.* is colloquial and will be understood by your listeners.

Comment: "Clinical depression" is a medical term of art.  "....lacking a cause by circumstances" is misleading. I have heard "clinical" applied sarcastically to other attributes, as in "He is clinically stupid", but that is a slang or idiosyncractic use.

Answer (score 0):

You can say *he has the blues* or *he feels blue*.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to use this term:

> John was *feeling* blue, he considered going out for a drink.
>
> John *is* blue today, I wonder what's wrong with him?
>
> John *had* the blues, he wanted to stay in bed all day under the covers.
>
> John was *playing the blues* after breaking up with his girlfriend.

Answer (score -1):

**Dysphoric**:

...it’s a negative feeling, especially about life in general. When someone is full of dysphoria, they’re dysphoric: unhappy. Being dysphoric is a lot like being depressed. If you are familiar with the Winnie-the-Pooh stories by A. A. Milne, then you know Eeyore — a dysphoric donkey.][1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41804/origin-of-the-of-the-phrase-feeling-blue)

They have the **[blues](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41804/origin-of-the-of-the-phrase-feeling-blue)** or he is in a **cafard**: [Depression, the blues](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41804/origin-of-the-of-the-phrase-feeling-blue)